# Appearing images with animation in scrollview effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I dont know if someone knows this effect. However, I saw sometimes in apps that if I scroll down the `ScrollView` some images appear through an `alpha` animation that I can rarely see the image appearing. I have a `scrollView` with about 30 images.

Is it possible to make this effect to my `scrollView` because I don't know if it is fix my issue too.

My issue is that the `view` loads so many pictures at one and sometimes crashes on `iPod touch 4G`. So my idea was t give my `scrollview` this awesome effect and maybe reduce the crashed trough that. I would be happy if someone could show me a sample.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't using animations further increase memory and CPU usage? If so, how would it help your app crash less frequently?

Comment: well...actually I dont think so. I think that it wouldn't crash if the images would be load while scrolling and not at once. So it is the "at once" which lets my app crash that so many images are loaded at the same time.

Comment: I think what you meant is [lazy loading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: actually not those images where just loaded. I want that the images alpha grow and it appears one image after the other one.

Comment: @H2CO3 using animations might use a very tiny bit more memory, but if you use the API's properly even the worst specced hardware can easily run animations on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so first of all you should probably consider using a tableview rather than a scrollview since what I think you're trying to achieve looks more like a list of images than anything else and yes this exists, and there are sample codes available from apple that show you how to do that called TableviewPlayground.

Second, how are you loading the images? a tableview is basically a 'lazy' view, you load the data thats on the screen, but not the rest in your datasource..

take a look at the tableview datasource protocol and properly implement the methods and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in particular.

[UITableViewDatasource protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource)

Comment: I actually load the images with the nib and not in the code files would that be a problem?

Comment: @NoahRaissi depends on the amount of images.. but yeah, if you are loading a lot of images through a NIB that means that when your view is loaded it will load all the images at once and therefore eat up so much memory that you will kill your own app.

Comment: isn't that for a table view? how can I use thi within a scrollview?

Comment: @NoahRaissi a scrollview is not made to display images one by one or series, a scrollview always loads an entire view. You need to figure out what exactly you're trying to do, then figure out what view you will need to use to solve your problem properly. It looks like you want to display a list of images, if the tableview doesn't provide the looks you need for it you can simply modify the cells you use in it.

Comment: hmmm...but I got a lot of those scrollviews it would be heavy work to do this.

Comment: @NoahRaissi so implementing a tableview from scratch is easier and takes less time rite?